# If $T$ is self-adjoint, then $T^2 + tI$ is bijective for any $t>0$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $I:H \to H$ be the indentity map. Let $T:H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator. In preparation for Brezis' *exercise 6.22.4*, I would like to prove that

> If $T$ is self-adjoint, then $T^2 + tI$ is bijective for any $t>0$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

First, we prove that $K:=T^2$ is positive, i.e., $\langle Ku, u \rangle \ge 0$ for all $u \in H$. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Ku, u \rangle &= \langle T^2u, u \rangle \\
&= \langle Tu, Tu \rangle \text{ because } T \text{ is self-adjoint} \\
&= |Tu|^2 \ge 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Second, we verify that $K+tI$ is injective. Let $u\in H$ such $(K+tI)u=0$. Then $Ku = -t u$. Then $u=0$ because
$$
0 \le \langle Ku, u \rangle = -t \langle u, u \rangle = -t|u|^2.
$$

Finally, we prove that $K+tI$ is surjective. We have $K^* = (T^2)^*=(T^*)^2=T^2=K$, so $K$ is self-adjoint. We have $(K+tI)^*= K^*+t I= K+tI$, so $K+tI$ is self-adjoint. For $u\in H$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
|(K+tI)u|^2 &= |Ku|^2 +2t \langle Ku, u \rangle + t^2|u|^2 \\
&\ge t^2|u|^2 + 2t \langle Ku, u \rangle \\
&\ge t^2|u|^2 \text{ because } K \text{ is positive}.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows from below *Theorem 2.21.* in the same book, i.e.,

> Let $E, F$ be real Banach spaces. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range. Let $A: D(A) \subset E \to F$ be an unbounded linear operator that is densely defined and has a closed graph.
>
> **Theorem 2.20.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A)=F$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |v| \leq C |A^* v| \quad \forall v \in D (A^*),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A^*) = \{0\}$ and $R(A^*)$ is closed.
>
> **Theorem 2.21.** The following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (a) $A^*$ is surjective, i.e., $R(A^*)=E^*$,
> - (b) there is a constant $C$ such that
>   $$
>   |u| \leq C |A u| \quad \forall u \in D (A),
>   $$
> - (c) $N (A) = \{0\}$ and $R(A)$ is closed.

Comment: Looks good to me. I don't know what you have available at that point, but $T^2+tId \geq t Id$ implies that $\text{spec}(T^2+t Id) \subseteq [t, \infty)$. In particular, $0\notin \text{spec}(T^2+t Id)$ and thus $T^2+t Id$ is invertible.